# Using a for loop to process multiple dataframes, how to save each processed dataframe in different excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am cleaning several excel spreadsheet through a for loop. At each iteration I want the dataframe to be saved in different spreadsheet. As shown in the code below I have five excel spreadsheet that are been cleaned and as an output I also want 5 different spreadsheet. I am kinda stuck. Below is the beginning of my code. I am just missing the saving file part to finalise the code.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import ExcelWriter


    datalist = ["Afzelia bipedensis_occurrence.xlsx", 
        "entandrophragma_occurence.xlsx", 
        "Khaya Anthotheca_occurence.xlsx", 
        "Milicia excelsa_occurrence.xlsx", 
        "Pericopsis elata_occurrence.xlsx"]

         print(datalist)


    for data in datalist:

        data1 = pd.read_excel(data)

        data2 = data1.groupby("countrycode")

        data3 = data2.get_group("CD")

        data4 = data3.dropna(how = "any", subset = ['decimalLatitude', 'decimalLongitude'])

        data5 = data4.drop_duplicates(subset ="decimalLatitude", keep = "first", inplace = False)

        print(data5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `for` loop, you may use [`pd.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and specify the output file name you want to use. For instance, you could want to use a slightly modified version of the input file name, adding a `_output` suffix:

```
data5.to_excel(data.replace(".xlsx", "_output.xlsx"))
```

That will save `Afzelia bipedensis_occurrence_output.xlsx` and so on.